# Transforming Scala case class into JSON

Tags: scala

I have two case classes. The main one, `Request`, contains two maps.
The first map has a string for both key and value.
The second map has a string key, and value which is an instance of the second case class, `KVMapList`.

```
case class Request (var parameters:MutableMap[String, String] = MutableMap[String, String](), var deps:MutableMap[String, KVMapList] = MutableMap[String, KVMapList]())

case class KVMapList(kvMap:MutableMap[String, String], list:ListBuffer[MutableMap[String, String]])
```

The requirement is to transform `Request` into a JSON representation.
The following code is trying to do this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

def test(req:Request):String {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL,  Visibility.ANY)
  var jsonInString: String = null
  try {
    jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(request)
  }
  catch {
    =case e: IOException => {
      e.printStackTrace
   }
  jsonString
}
```

This however is not working. Even when the `Request` class is populated, the output is :

```
{"parameters":{"underlying":{"some-value":""},"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true},"deps":{"sizeMapDefined":false,"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}}
```

Using the JSON object mapper with corresponding Java classes is straightforward, but have not yet got it working in Scala. Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Jackson is more of a bad old memory in Scala to some degree. You should use a native Scala library for JSON processing, particularly one really good at compile time derivation of JSON serializers, such as [**circe**](https://github.com/circe/circe).

I'm aware this doesn't directly answer your question, but after using circe I would never go back to anything else.

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._

val req = new Request(...)
val json = req.asJson.noSpaces
val reparsed = decode[Request](json)
```

On a different note, using mutable maps inside case classes is as non-idiomatic as it gets, and it should be quite trivial to implement immutable ops for your maps using the auto-generated `copy` method.

```
case class Request(parameters: Map[String, String] {
  def +(key: String, value: String): Request = {
    this.copy(parameters = parameters + (key -> value))
  }
}
```

You should really avoid mutability wherever possible, and it looks like avoiding it here wouldn't be much work at all.

Comment: There is a maven build failure when compiling req.asJson.noSpaces: error: scala.MatchError: true (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Literal). Am using jars circe-parse_sjs0.6_2.11 and circe-generic_2.11 (both from group io.circe). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what this `ScalaObjectMapper` does, doesn't look like it is useful.
If you add `mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)` in the beginning, it should work ... assuming that by `MutableMap` you mean `mutable.Map`, and not some sort of home-made class (because, if you do, you'd have to provide a serializer for it yourself).

(`DefaultScalaModule` is in [jackson-module-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11) library. Just add it to your build if you don't already have it).

Comment: This exception is thrown when registerModule is called: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/AsArraySerializerBase;

Comment: You must be using a wrong version. The versions of jackson core and scala module libraries must be the the same.

Comment: Thanks Dima. Fixed another issue, now this is error: Scala module 2.9.0 requires Jackson Databind version >= 2.9.0 and < 2.10.0. However, cannot find Jackson-databind with version higher than 2.9.0.pr3

Comment: Give it the version it requires? What's that 'pr3' stuff? Get rid of it

Comment: Thanks Dima. It's kind of working now, all the values are written out. The issue is that the JSON also contains KVMapList, i.e, the name of the class, it should only contain the values in that class. In Java this is solved by annotating the corresponding (inner) class with @JsonValue. That does not appear to work in Scala.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. I don't see any inner classes in your code. And when I write a `Request` class to json as it is defined in your question, there are no classnames in the output.